# Is there an XP limit on UGC missions?

Tags: infamous-2

When playing User Generated Content missions I don't seem to be getting the proper XP when I kill enemies. When the mission starts if I watch my XP, kills seem to give full XP, but after a few I start very rarely getting XP. The +X XP notifications on the side appear as normal, but *definitely* don't add up to the actual XP I earn.

I've noticed in particular the Ionic Drain/ect super attacks seem to always give 0 XP.

Is there some limit on experience gain in UGC missions in Infamous 2? What is it and how does it work?

Comment: I thought that you can't earn exp in UGC missions. Or if you do, then it's really low

Comment: @Novarg you can, but it is pretty low. Most I've gotten is 140. But like I said, at the start you get full XP for each kill (except from Ionic attacks) but then it seems to cap

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe there is a limit, and if there is it's a lot because I think it depends on how well you play the mission and how long it takes.